# Как отследить клик мыши

Tags: c#

Вопрос теоретический, как отследить нажатие левой кнопки мыши с помощью c#. Делаю некую задачу, где по клику мышкой делается скриншет экрана. Ну со скриншетом я разобрался, а вот как отследить сам клик увы пока не получается. Возможно есть некоторые хуки windows, которые можно использовать, но тут встает вопрос везде ли это будет работать.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Можно воспользоваться [Processing Global Mouse and Keyboard Hooks in C#](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/7294/Processing-Global-Mouse-and-Keyboard-Hooks-in-C)

Потребуется подключение `Gma.UserActivityMonitor.dll` к Вашему проекту.

В VS Studio это делается так:

1. Строите Gma.UserActivityMonitor.dll из исходных текстов.
   Потом в своём проекте:
2. Раскрываете в Solution Explorer дерево проекта
3. Кликаете правой кнопкой на узле References и выбираете "Add reference..."
4. В диалоге "Add reference" выбираете закладку "Browse"
5. Находите и добавляете Gma.UserActivityMonitor.dll

Comment: Спасибо, по описанию то что нужно, а как на счет работоспособности в win10?

Comment: Затрудняюсь сказать, на 7-ке видел что используют

Comment: Там же нашел [комментарий, что да](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/7294/Processing-Global-Mouse-and-Keyboard-Hooks-in-C?msg=5389560#xx5389560xx)

Comment: Тогда точно то что нужно, спасибо.